# $z_1,...z_n$ are the $n$ solutions of $z^n =a$ and $a$ is real number, show that $z_1+...+z_n$ is a real number

Tags: complex-numbers

I was actually trying this simple question, might be just me being really rusty not doing maths for a very long time. I tried adding all the $\theta$ up on all zs but it doesn't seem to work.

Anyway as the title states,

$z_1,...z_n$ are the $n$ solutions of  $z^n =a$ and $a$ is real number, show that $z_1+...+z_n$ is a real number.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that the roots of $z^n-a = 0$ are either real or occur in conjugate pairs?  If so, the proof is trivial.  If not, what are you permitted to use?

Comment: In general, the sum of the solutions of p(z)=0 is equal to negative the coefficient of $x^{(n-1)}$, which in this case is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Two observations:

1. If $z$ is a root of $x^n = a$, then $\overline{z}$ is as well, since $\overline{z}^n = \overline{(z^n)} = \overline{a} = a$.
2. $z + \overline{z}$ is real.

Now do you see why it's true?

Comment: There is much simpler...

Comment: @Did There are several very simple ways of seeing this. Whether one is *much* simpler seems to me a matter of opinion...

Comment: yes i see why this is true but that does not answer the question. $z+\bar{z}$ is real does not mean $z_1+z_2$ is real

Comment: Pair up each non-real root with its complex conjugate, which also appears on the list, and add them. Each time, you get a real number. Now you're left with a sum of real numbers.

Comment: You see... Absolute relativism about matters of mathematical simplicity is not a very sustainable position.

Answer (score 3):

Use thae fact that $$z^n -a =z^n -(z_1 +...+z_n ) z^{n-1} +...+ z_1 \cdot z_2 \cdot ...\cdot z_n $$